# 'Open File' Dialogue Detection

Tags: c++, windows, automation

I'm extending the functionality of a automated GUI clicker (literally blasts an interface with thousands of random clicks). It's written in C++ under Windows and is, so far, very effective. The only I've encountered so far is, some of the software I'm testing allows the user to import files, so it opens the 'Open File' dialogue popup when a particular button is hit. The rest of the GUI is unresponsive until you've closed this dialogue. So my question is this:

Is there a way to detect such a popup? So it can be closed as soon as it occurs.

Comment: Explore Windows hooks and window messages.